# Query Timeout Settings in Excel

Tags: sql-server-2005, excel, timeout

new to the site I'd like to give it a shot and see if I can get any answers regarding SQL Querys in Excel.

Is there a way to handle if a Timeout occurs in Microsoft Excel (mostly 2007/2010 on Win XP/Vista/7)? As you know you can connect Excel to a Microsoft SQL Server and run your query via Excel. The only thing is that I don't seem to find any Timeout options for this. And for an example, if there is a bad query, this might lock other tables in the SQL Server (2005) database.

I'm not looking for a script. It's more like settings I need and if possible I would like to add these Timeout settings to a specific Windows user account. Settings in either SQL Server 2005 or in Microsoft Excel 2007/2010.

Best regards
/Henrik

Answer (score 0):

Use the **CommandTimeout** property

```
Dim objCommand As ADODB.Command
Set objCommand = New ADODB.Command

objCommand.CommandTimeout = 99 '
objCommand.ActiveConnection = cnConn
objCommand.CommandText = "DELETE Users WHERE IdLevel < 98"
objCommand.Execute
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for the quick reply, but I'm looking more for some settings in either Excel or SQL server, regarding specific users. Maby you know something about this also? BR /Henrik

Comment: You can't do that in Excel without VBA.  The above VBA codes you can use in an Excel macro to set the timeout.